# has_many through with scope condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, relationship

I am new to Rails and have a question on putting a condition on a `has_many :through` relationship. I want to have a `:joined_groups` relationship in the `FacebookUser` model. The joined_groups would be a through the GroupInvite table meeting the condition of `where(accepted: true)`. However I do not know how to accomplish this with Rails or if this is even the right way of doing it. I have the following models ...

**Group.rb**

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :name

  ...

  #Relationships
  has_many :group_invites, class_name: 'GroupInvite'
  has_many :facebook_users, class_name: 'FacebookUser', :through => :group_invites, :source => :facebook_user
end
```

**GroupInvite.rb**

```
class GroupInvite < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :accepted, :facebook_user_uid, :group_id, :admin

  ...    

  #Relationships
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :facebook_user, :foreign_key => :facebook_user_uid, :primary_key => :facebook_user_uid

  #Scopes
  scope :pending, where(accepted: nil)
  scope :declined, where(accepted: false)
  scope :joined, where(accepted: true)
end
```

**FacebookUser**

```
class FacebookUser < ActiveRecord::Base

  #Attributes
  attr_accessible :first_name, :gender, :last_name, :uid

  ...

  has_many :group_invites, class_name: 'GroupInvite', :primary_key => :uid, :foreign_key => :facebook_user_uid
  has_many :groups, class_name: 'Group', :through => :group_invites, :source => :group
  ...
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
has_many :accepted_group_invites, class_name: 'GroupInvite', :primary_key => :uid, :foreign_key => :facebook_user_uid, :conditions => { :accepted => true }
```

Matta